# How can i repopulate the dropdown list in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to make a dropdown list that when one item is selected then the other dropdown will change it's list

So fart this is what i've done, 
This **first** dropdown that **will change** the list of another dropdown:

```
<select id="testers_team-${info.problemId}" class="tester_team">
    <optgroup label="Current Value">
         <option><c:out value="${info.team}"></c:out></option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Teams">
         <c:forEach var="team" items="${requestScope.testers}">
        <option value="${team.key}">${team.key}</option>
         </c:forEach>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

This is the **second** dropdown that **will be change** if another dropdown is selected:

```
<select id="testers" class="testers_team-${info.problemId}">
    <optgroup label="Current Assigned Tester">
        <option>I'll think about this later</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Testers">
          <c:forEach var="testers_per_team" items='${test.KwekKwek}'>
               <option>${testers_per_team}</option>
          </c:forEach>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

This code is the `Ajax` that get the proper value and send it back that should be repopulating the dropdown:

```
$('.tester_team').each(function(){
             $(this).change(function() {
                 var id = $(this).attr('id');

                  $.post('Analysis',
                     {team: $(this).val()},
                     function(data)
                     {
                        $('.'+id).each(function()
                        {
                            $(this).find('option').remove();
                            $.each(data, function(index, value) {              
                                $('<option>').text(value).appendTo($select);
                            });
                        });

                     },"json"); 
             }); 
         });
```

What is done already is:

1. Send to the servlet the selected value of the first dropdown
2. Process the value so it will return the proper value to repopulate the second dropdown
3. Get the value in `JSON` form
4. Removed the list from the SECOND dropdown when another value is selected on the FIRST dropdown

The problem is the repopulating itself, is used

```
$.each(data, function(index, value) {              
    $('<option>').text(value).appendTo($select);
});
```

to repopulate the list of the SECOND dropdown but it seems that code is wrong. Please help me to resolve this.

**NOTE**: Both dropdown is iterated by `foreach` thats why is used the `id` of the first dropdown to identify the second dropdown relative to it. And about the data that send back by the servlet, it is not null, i tried to pop it out in an `alert();` and it is there.

Comment: What is $select on your appendTo ?

Comment: Is that should be an id?

Comment: @fliim Silly me. I should put the direct class. Just one more question how can i only change the list of `<optgroup label="Testers">` ?

Comment: you can select an element with a specific attribute value by using ELEMENT[ATTR=VALUE] selector. See doc here: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/
or here for you case: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this ?

```
$('.'+id).each(function()
  {
    $(this).find('option').remove();
    var optgroup = $("optgroup[label=Testers]", this);
    $.each(data, function(index, value) {              
      $('<option>').text(value).appendTo(optgroup);
    });
  })
```

Comment: the `$(this).find('option').remove();` removes all the option of the dropdown, how can i remove the `second optgroup` without destroying the `first optgroup`

Comment: You just have to use the attribute selector that I show you in your first post comment. or you can take as example from the code above :)

Comment: could you give an example of how to remove an option of a specific `<optgroup>`, the `<select>` should have two optgroup.